# Form of the Lagrangian for 1D String Dynamics

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, differentiation, lattice-model

I am currently reading part of Franz Gross' Relativistic Quantum Mechanics and Field Theory, and am getting stuck on a particular point in chapter 1 where he attempts to motivate field theory by taking the continuum limit of a series of oscillators arranged on a string.

We are given that the kinetic energy and potential energy are:

$$
KE = \frac{1}{2}m\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}{(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t})}
$$

$$
PE = \frac{1}{2}k\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}{(\phi_{i+1}-\phi_{i})^2}
$$

We are free to introduce mutually cancelling distance values $l$ as we need to take the continuum limit and form integrals, a la:

$$
PE = \frac{1}{2}kl\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}{l(\frac{\phi_{i+1}-\phi_{i}}{l})^2} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}T\int_{0}^{L}{dz(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z})^2} 
$$

Now, the Lagrangian can be formed by taking $KE-PE$, or:

$$
L = \int_{0}^{L}{dz\frac{1}{2}\mu(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t})^2}- \frac{1}{2}T{(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z})^2} = \int_{0}^{L}{dz \textit{L(z,t)} } 
$$

Our next goal is to formulate the necessary partial derivatives of this expression to form the Euler-Lagrange equations of motion, solutions of the system of equations:

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot\phi_i} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_i} = 0
$$

And this is where I get lost. This is page 6, and the very next step taken after mentioning the Euler-Lagrange equations is to produce the form of $ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_i}$. All that is stated is:

> "...in the continuum limit as the number of oscillators N $\rightarrow \infty $, 
>   $$
> \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_i} = -k[-(\phi_{i+1}-\phi_i)+(\phi_{i}-\phi_{i-1})]
> $$
>   $$
> = kl[\frac{(\phi_{i+1}-\phi_i)}{l}-\frac{(\phi_{i}-\phi_{i-1})}{l}]
> $$
>   $$
> \rightarrow_{small\space\space\space l}  lT\frac{1}{l}[\frac{\partial\phi(z^+,t)}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial\phi(z^-,t)}{\partial z}]
> $$
>   $$
> \rightarrow_{absorb \space \sqrt{T}} -l\sqrt{T}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial L(z,t)}{\partial (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z})}
> $$"

Where $L(z,t)$ is the Lagrangian density, the integrand in the original Lagrangian expression.

This first step, where we automatically jump into the expression $
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_i} = -k[-(\phi_{i+1}-\phi_i)+(\phi_{i}-\phi_{i-1})]$ does not make sense to me.

I can see that the expression inside the brackets is the numerator of a second order central difference approximation, ie: $\frac{\phi_{i+1}+\phi_{i-1}-2\phi_{i}}{l^2} \rightarrow \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z^2} $, but I cannot see how we get here in the first place.

By my reckoning, the expression inside the $PE$ expression reduces to 
$$
\frac{1}{2}k\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}{(\phi_{i+1}^2+\phi_{i}^2-2\phi_{i+1}\phi_{i})}
$$

And I can see how we might gain a term of the kind:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_i}\frac{1}{2}k\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}{(\phi_{i+1}^2+\phi_{i}^2-2\phi_{i+1}\phi_{i})} = \frac{2}{2}k\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}{(\phi_{i}-\phi_{i+1})}
$$

But I do not see how this can then be taken forward as they do. My suspicion is that there is something simply I am missing, as other workups of similar material (as in continuous oscillations on a rod instead of a circular string) also jump directly into this simplification (see https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/grad/618/lects/classMech_2.pdf).

Can anyone explain to me how this mid-point result is achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing something very simple. There are two appearances of the variable $\phi_i$ in that sum
$$\frac{d}{d\phi_i}\sum_j(\phi_{j+1}-\phi_j)^2=\frac{d}{d\phi_i}\left((\phi_{i+1}-\phi_i)^2+(\phi_{i}-\phi_{i-1})^2\right)=-2(\phi_{i+1}-\phi_i)+2(\phi_{i}-\phi_{i-1})$$

Comment: Thanks for responding octonion! Just to be clear. Am I right in summarizing your answer to be a change of variables? As in, setting
$$
\phi_{j+1} \rightarrow \phi_i
$$

Such that $\frac{d}{d\phi_i}\sum_j(\phi_{j+1}-\phi_j)^2 = \frac{d}{d\phi_i}[(\phi_{j+1}-\phi_j)^2+\sum_j(\phi_{j+2}-\phi_{j+1})^2]$, and $\frac{d}{d\phi_i}[(\phi_{j+1}-\phi_j)^2+\sum_j(\phi_{j+2}-\phi_{j+1})^2] = \frac{d}{d\phi_i}[(\phi_{i}-\phi_{i-1})^2+\sum_i(\phi_{i+1}-\phi_{i})^2]$?

If so though, how does the summation sign resolve?

Comment: @Yajibromine, No it is not a change of variables. $i$ refers to a particular value of the index, $j$ is the index appearing in the summation. Perhaps it would be clearer if you substitute a number like 2 instead of $i$. There are two terms in the summation that contain $\phi_2$, that's what I was pointing out. You were only noticing one.

Comment: Say $i \rightarrow 0$, we would have for the sum $\frac{d}{d\phi_0}\sum_0(\phi_{0+1}-\phi_0)^2$:

$$
\frac{d}{d\phi_0}\sum_0(\phi_{0+1}-\phi_0)^2 = \frac{d}{d\phi_0} \left[ (\phi_{1}-\phi_0)^2 +(\phi_{2}-\phi_1)^2 +(\phi_{3}-\phi_2)^2 + ...\right]
$$

There is only one term which contains $\phi_0$. In the original question, we sum from $i = 0$ to $i = N-1$, so we would not have a term with $\phi_{-1}$

Comment: Of course, for any number greater than zero this fails and your method works (ie:$...+(\phi_{2}-\phi_1)^2 +(\phi_{3}-\phi_2)^2...$ , which makes me think I'm getting stuck on something else. Is there something wrong with the $\partial \phi_0$ argument?

Comment: @Yajibromine, You are correct that there is only one term for the two lattice points on the boundary given your choice of boundary conditions.